# fabric.js - fill an image with pattern

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using Fabcy product designer and fabric.js for custom t-shirts and I need to fill a png image with a pattern but I didn't found examples that do that.

I tried with some snippet like the follow but it didn't works:

```
fabric.util.loadImage(url, function(img) {
    element.fill = new fabric.Pattern({
        source: img,
        repeat: 'repeat'
    });
    stage.renderAll.bind(stage); 
});
```

Can you help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, I shall work on that feature as soon as possible